# PyCharm ImportError: how can you import your own modules?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working with Python 2.7.3 using PyCharm in Mountain Lion. I'm trying to build my own library with functions that I use often.

I added the library directory to the system path, and to the Pythonpath, and everything works correctly using the terminal, but not in PyCharm.

I've set the Project Interpreter to be the one that I'm using in the terminal, and checked that the paths are OK, but I'm not able to use my modules from PyCharm. 
When I do:

```
import my_lib
```

and execute it, it says:

```
ImportError: No module named my_lib
```

The folder structure I use is like this:

```
/Users/myuser/code/__init__.py
                  /my_lib/__init__.py
                         /function1
                         /function2
                         / ...
```

And the path includes */Users/myuser/code* and I've added _/Users/myuser/code/my_lib_ with the hope that this was the problem but had no luck. By the way, both of the init files are empty.

Does any of you know why this would happen?

Comment: Note: you should **not** put an `__init__.py` under the `code` directory. If `code` is just a random directory containing source code you just mark it as Source Root and you're fine. If `code` needs to be a package, then you should change the imports from `import mylib` to `import code.mylib`. The modules defined inside the package should use explicit relative imports such as `from . import function1` or `from .. import mylib`  and I'd suggest to add `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of your files to avoid implicit relative imports...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand completely but, I think you are looking for following solution.

To be able to add a lib from specific path, you can use

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "my_lib/function1)
# suppose that in function1, there is mylib.py file so

import mylib
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your library to the "External Libraries" That are visible in Project Window.

What id is coping my lib folder to the C:\Python\Lib\My_lib

Work like a charm ;)